# Vertx user authorization principal or attributes

Tags: java, jwt, vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vertx4

I am using the Vertx framework on my API for authorization with JWT tokens. After the user is authorized and the token is decrypted I want to access the contents of the token, particularly a "userId" field within the token.

Originally I was accessing this with `req` as the `RoutingContext` as:

`req.user().principal().getString("userId");`

This works as intended until it is compiled on a different machine. When compiled on a different machine `req.user().principal()` only contains the field `access_token`, containing the still encrypted JWT.

The solution to this was to access the user ID through

`req.user().attributes().getJsonObject("accessToken").getString("userId");`

I've tested this on 4 different machines. 2 of them work using principal, and the other 2 require attributes. It seems to only matter which machine it is *compiled* on, not what it is run on. The code is not being changed between machines. Java, Maven, and Vertx versions are the same each time.

Some solutions I've found online simply check if the needed field is in principal, and if not to use attributes instead. This seems like a bad workaround though. There has to be a proper way to access it.

What is the proper way to access the values within the decoded token? And why does it seem to change depending on the compiling machine?

Answer (score 1):

In vert.x 3.x the tokens were always decoded to a JSON object and this object would be the `principal`. In vert.x 4 a lot of work has been done on the auth n/z area so the rule of thumb is:

- `principal` contains the "source" properties that allowed the creation of this `User` object.
- `attributes` contains decoded/generated properties during the auth n/z process.

So you should expect the decoded token to always be on `attributes` if you're using vert.x 4. A recent commit added back those properties to the `principal` for JWT auth in order to keep it backwards compatible.

The details: The reason why the token is now not decoded to the `principal` is because `User` objects are decoupled from auth providers. So Even though a `User` was created from `JWTAuth` it could be used by `OAuth2Auth`. So the internal structure needs to be consistent. Second, Oauth2 with OpenID Connect also uses tokens, but there are several kinds of tokens:

1. `access_token`
2. `id_token`

Decoding these tokens to the principal would mean that, in some cases properties could overlap. One of these overlaps would be the properties related to expiration/validity of the token. Getting the whole `User` validation in a wrong state in some situations.

Finally, we can now use vertx auth for server side auth n/z but also for client auth. This means we need to preserve the original raw token (which is the principal) so we can quickly add it without tampering to a client request in order to perform auth "on behalf of".